# How to reuse a File Handler to open multiple files

Tags: file

I have to write a piece of code where I can't predetermine the filename that I will be creating.

Due to this I would like to keep a single File Handler. Close this. Create another file using the same file handler.

## Sample Code:

```
public void sample(String input)  
{  
    // The value of this string changes dynamically                                            
    // and accordingly a new file with that needs to be created.

    String fileName = input; 
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter bw= new BufferedWriter(fw);

    // code to write contents to that file.
    bw.close();
}
```

Now, I will be invoking this function "sample" multiple times with different file names.

When I tried the above sample code, am getting NullPointerException. Can anyone guide me as to where am going wrong?

Regards,
Harish

Comment: On which line do you get the NPE? Can you show the error log please?